# TabPanel-like Button style for a regular Button

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to create a TabPanel like Button out of a regular `com.emitrom.gwt4.touch.client.widgets.Button`

I mean, `TabPanel` buttons are used to switch between tabs, and have this *"pushed down"* effect when a certain tab is selected, as it style blends properly with the `TabBar` of the `TabPanel`. I am not after the tab switching function but more on the push button function of a `TabPanel` button.

With `TabPanel` buttons are automatically inserted as `TabPanel` item is inserted. Looking at the code I can see that items are styled with: `item.setIconCls(TouchIcons.INFO)`, so I set my `button.setIconCls(TouchIcons.INFO)` but the effect is not the same.

For some reason I can't use `TabPanel` so I just need to have this push button style with regular `Button` or if there's a PushButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here: http://www.emitrom.com/node/313

> The Button class does not support this feature. What you could do is use the SegmentedButton class with only one button and setAllowMultiple to true. That should do the trick.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Pat.

Regards.